# tokenize the string and select the specific values

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am working on XSLT2 script where the variable contains following text:

`<xsl:variable name="urlparams" select="'color=red;rating=5;page=8;product=xyz'"/>`

I want to construct below url. The equal to (=) values are dynamic, so next time it may change. For example (color=blue or product=abc).

`<a href="www.google.com/?color=red&product=xyz"/>`

Here is my xslt but it is not working :(

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="urlparams" select="'color=red;rating=5;page=8;product=xyz'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'www.google.com/?'"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($urlparams, ';')">
            <xsl:if test=". = 'color'">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&amp;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test=". = 'product'">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Change xsl:if test=". = 'color'" to xsl:if test="starts-with(. , 'color' )">

Comment: Thanks @SiebeJongebloed. This helps. Question: If there is only 'color' param then there is no need of '&' at the end. How to conditionalize that so it wont be added in url?

Comment: Ok. I will put <text>&amp;</text> before the product. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a pure XPath 2.0 expression whose evaluation produces the wanted result:**

```
      for $host in 'www.google.com/',
          $qParams in 'color=red;rating=5;page=8;product=xyz',
          $qString in string-join(tokenize($qParams, ';')
                                  [starts-with(., 'color=') or starts-with(., 'product=')],
                                 '&amp;')
         return
           concat($host, '?'[$qString], $qString)
```

**XSLT  2.0 based validation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="vUrl" select=
     "for $host in 'www.google.com/',
            $qParams in 'color=red;rating=5;page=8;product=xyz',
            $qString in string-join(tokenize($qParams, ';')
                         [starts-with(., 'color=') or starts-with(., 'product=')], 
                                  '&amp;')
         return
           concat($host, '?'[$qString], $qString)
     "/>
     
     <a href="{$vUrl}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on any source XML document (not used), it evaluates the XPath expression and inserts the result as **[AVT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates)** as the value of the `href` attribute of the wanted `<a>` element, producing the wanted, correct result:

**`<a href="www.google.com/?color=red&amp;product=xyz"></a>`**

---

**Part II**

One can even avoid hard-coding the wanted QS parameter -names, by presenting them within a parameter, like this:

```
for $host in 'www.google.com/',
    $wantedPNames in '|color|product|',
    $qParams in 'color=red;rating=5;page=8;product=xyz',
    $qString in string-join(tokenize($qParams, ';')
                         [contains($wantedPNames, concat('|',tokenize(., '=')[1], '|'))],
                           '&amp;')
   return
     concat($host, '?'[$qString], $qString)
```

**Evaluating the XPath expression above, again produces the wanted, correct result**:

`www.google.com/?color=red&product=xyz`

**Here is again the XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html"/>
 <xsl:param name="wantedPNames" select="'|color|product|'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="vUrl" select=
     "for $host in 'www.google.com/',
          $qParams in 'color=red;rating=5;page=8;product=xyz',
          $qString in string-join(tokenize($qParams, ';')
                         [contains($wantedPNames, concat('|',tokenize(., '=')[1], '|'))],
                                 '&amp;')
   return
     concat($host, '?'[$qString], $qString)
     "/>
     
     <a href="{$vUrl}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Again the same correct and wanted result is produced**:

**`<a href="www.google.com/?color=red&amp;product=xyz"></a>`**

---

**The OP asked additionally**: "*Question: If there is only 'color' param then there is no need of '&' at the end. How to conditionalize that so it wont be added in url?* "

**Answer**: This same solution works correctly in such cases:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html"/>
 <xsl:param name="wantedPNames" select="'|color|'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="vUrl" select=
     "for $host in 'www.google.com/',
          $qParams in 'color=red;rating=5;page=8;product=xyz',
          $qString in string-join(tokenize($qParams, ';')
                         [contains($wantedPNames, concat('|',tokenize(., '=')[1], '|'))],
                                 '&amp;')
   return
     concat($host, '?'[$qString], $qString)
     "/>

     <a href="{$vUrl}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Again the correct result is produced**:

**`<a href="www.google.com/?color=red"></a>`**

**Even if no parameters are passed, the result of this same solution will still be correct**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html"/>
 <xsl:param name="wantedPNames" select="'||'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="vUrl" select=
     "for $host in 'www.google.com/',
          $qParams in 'color=red;rating=5;page=8;product=xyz',
          $qString in string-join(tokenize($qParams, ';')
                         [contains($wantedPNames, concat('|',tokenize(., '=')[1], '|'))],
                                 '&amp;')
   return
     concat($host, '?'[$qString], $qString)
     "/>

     <a href="{$vUrl}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Again the correct result**:

**`<a href="www.google.com/"></a>`**